# pandas: rolling mean not working

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame as follows:

```
         Dates  Var_1   Var_2
0   2018-01-09  612.0  368.0  
1   2018-01-10  348.0  348.0  
2   2018-01-11  350.0  337.0  
3   2018-01-12  335.0  337.0  
4   2018-01-13  334.0 900.0  
5   2018-01-14  325.0  325.0 
6   2018-01-15  580.0  317.0 
7   2018-01-16  334.0 900.0  
8   2018-01-17  325.0  325.0
```

I tried to calculate mean of each 3 rolling elements for each column.
For example:

```
mean of 2018-01-09, 2018-01-10, 2018-01-11 >> 2018-01-10
mean of 612.0, 348.0, 350.0 >> 436.66
```

Then, output `3 rows by 2 columns` pandas dataframe.

I tried as:

```
result = df.set_index('Dates').rolling(3).mean().reset_index()
```

But unsuccessful.
Please help me, guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by floor divide `np.arange` by `3` and if want also mean of `datetimes` need convert to `np.int64` for native unix datetimes in `nanoseconds` and last convert back:

```
print (np.arange(len(df)))
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]

print (np.arange(len(df)) // 3)
[0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2]

df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates']).astype(np.int64)
print (df)
                 Dates  Var_1  Var_2
0  1515456000000000000  612.0  368.0
1  1515542400000000000  348.0  348.0
2  1515628800000000000  350.0  337.0
3  1515715200000000000  335.0  337.0
4  1515801600000000000  334.0  900.0
5  1515888000000000000  325.0  325.0
6  1515974400000000000  580.0  317.0
7  1516060800000000000  334.0  900.0
8  1516147200000000000  325.0  325.0
```

---

```
df = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 3).mean()
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])
print (df)
       Dates       Var_1       Var_2
0 2018-01-10  436.666667  351.000000
1 2018-01-13  331.333333  520.666667
2 2018-01-16  413.000000  514.000000
```

If omit converting, `Dates` column is silently removed, because [automatic exclusion of nuisance columns](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#automatic-exclusion-of-nuisance-columns).

```
df = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 3).mean()
print (df)
        Var_1       Var_2
0  436.666667  351.000000
1  331.333333  520.666667
2  413.000000  514.000000
```

Comment: @brute - it is floor divide, give me some time for explanation.

Comment: by the way, in my program, Dates are casted in this format `2018-01-10 12:00:00`. How can I change it into `2018-01-10` format?

Comment: @brute - I suggest use `df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates']).dt.floor('d')`

Comment: @brute - it remove all times and still datetimes.

Comment: @brute - what about `dt.normalize()` ? [`normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Dates': ['2018-01-09', '2018-01-10', '2018-01-11', '2018-01-12', '2018-01-15', '2018-01-16', '2018-01-17'],
        'var1': [612, 348, 350, 335, 334, 325, 580]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

result = df['var1'].rolling(window=3).mean()
```

Sorry for my first reply - rolling_mean() has been deprecated, so I wanted to completely replace it.  This is working for me.

Comment: but it did not reduce the df into `3 rows by 2 columns`